# Ho do I generate eclipse project without compiling or ignoring compilation errors using SBT and play framework?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.2

Recently our project's dependencies artifact name has been changed so as the package names and some classes' names. Now we need to update our project dependencies for our next release. Problem is when invoking eclipse from play console it just doesn't do that if there's any compilation errors which of course is expected. I just want to update the eclipse project settings and fix compilation problems later.

Answer (score 0):

It should generate the projects even if there are compilation problems. You might want to check your sbteclipse version.

There might be a chance that it will not even compile when generating the eclipse files. This could theoretically be triggered by a related sbt issue: [`compile` is executed for `discoveredSbtPlugins` when the project is not a plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1670)

So if you are not creating an sbt plugin and have an updated sbteclipse version and still have problems, you could try setting: `discoveredSbtPlugins := PluginDiscovery.emptyDiscoveredNames`.

I would strongly advise you to first see if the compilation problems are causing the projects not to be created. In the past I have often created projects when I had compiler errors. It will for example not create the project if you have an unresolved dependency.